# when install mysql-proxy No package 'lua5.1' found

Tags: mysql

OS is centos5.4. lua is 5.1.4. mysql-proxy is 0.7.1. 
lua5.1.pc is already in /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/
$PKG_CONFIG_PATH is /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
why it shows error：

> checking for LUA... no checking for
>   LUA... configure: error: Package
>   requirements (lua5.1 >= 5.1) were not
>   met:
>
> No package 'lua5.1' found

when i configure mysql-proxy?

Answer (score 1):

Open `/etc/profile`  as super user
     vi /etc/profile

and add the following content:

```
export LUA_CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/lua/include"
export LUA_LIBS="-L/usr/local/lua/lib -llua -ldl"
```

save the file and then execute the below as super user.

```
source /etc/profile
```